# How to read PDF417 data

Tags: c#, utf-8

I am trying to copy the functionality of an application and further develop it.

This app generates a document with a PDF417 bar-code in which it stores the form data the user has entered.

In order for me to know how to arrange the data the user enters in my app in the string I firstly need to decode the already generated code.

What I am able to read is:

```
PDF417 scan data:

String data:

DZ65Y6JmY0ykW0uuGGzWPVWQ==    000000000060000000000101102016120MQA5ADAAMQAyADIANgA0ADYAMAAwADIAMwA=                                                                                                                                        UgBPADEANgBCAFAATwBTADgAMQAwADAAOQAzADkAMwAwADIAOABSAE8ATgAwADEA1000000012000000023NU000000400000025500004046600000005700000006800000100900000008A00000009B00084200C00000011D00001687E00000166FNU000000GNU000000RQB1AGcAZQBuAA==                                                                                                        SQBuAGcAaQBuAGUAcgA=                                                                                                    5
PDF417 raw data:
Total elements: 1
Element #1 is of type text
Length = 684 {68, 90, 54, 53, 89, 54, 74, 109, 89, 48, 121, 107, 87, 48, 117, 117, 71, 71, 122, 87, 80, 86, 87, 81, 61, 61, 32, 32, 32, 32, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 54, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 49, 48, 49, 49, 48, 50, 48, 49, 54, 49, 50, 48, 77, 81, 65, 53, 65, 68, 65, 65, 77, 81, 65, 121, 65, 68, 73, 65, 78, 103, 65, 48, 65, 68, 89, 65, 77, 65, 65, 119, 65, 68, 73, 65, 77, 119, 65, 61, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 85, 103, 66, 80, 65, 68, 69, 65, 78, 103, 66, 67, 65, 70, 65, 65, 84, 119, 66, 84, 65, 68, 103, 65, 77, 81, 65, 119, 65, 68, 65, 65, 79, 81, 65, 122, 65, 68, 107, 65, 77, 119, 65, 119, 65, 68, 73, 65, 79, 65, 66, 83, 65, 69, 56, 65, 84, 103, 65, 119, 65, 68, 69, 65, 49, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 49, 50, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 50, 51, 78, 85, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 52, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 50, 53, 53, 48, 48, 48, 48, 52, 48, 52, 54, 54, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 53, 55, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 54, 56, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 49, 48, 48, 57, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 56, 65, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 57, 66, 48, 48, 48, 56, 52, 50, 48, 48, 67, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 49, 49, 68, 48, 48, 48, 48, 49, 54, 56, 55, 69, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 49, 54, 54, 70, 78, 85, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 71, 78, 85, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 82, 81, 66, 49, 65, 71, 99, 65, 90, 81, 66, 117, 65, 65, 61, 61, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 83, 81, 66, 117, 65, 71, 99, 65, 97, 81, 66, 117, 65, 71, 85, 65, 99, 103, 65, 61, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 53}
Text representation (UTF-8 decoded): DZ65Y6JmY0ykW0uuGGzWPVWQ==    000000000060000000000101102016120MQA5ADAAMQAyADIANgA0ADYAMAAwADIAMwA=                                                                                                                                        UgBPADEANgBCAFAATwBTADgAMQAwADAAOQAzADkAMwAwADIAOABSAE8ATgAwADEA1000000012000000023NU000000400000025500004046600000005700000006800000100900000008A00000009B00084200C00000011D00001687E00000166FNU000000GNU000000RQB1AGcAZQBuAA==                                                                                                        SQBuAGcAaQBuAGUAcgA=                                                                                                    5

PDF417 raw data merged:
{68, 90, 54, 53, 89, 54, 74, 109, 89, 48, 121, 107, 87, 48, 117, 117, 71, 71, 122, 87, 80, 86, 87, 81, 61, 61, 32, 32, 32, 32, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 54, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 49, 48, 49, 49, 48, 50, 48, 49, 54, 49, 50, 48, 77, 81, 65, 53, 65, 68, 65, 65, 77, 81, 65, 121, 65, 68, 73, 65, 78, 103, 65, 48, 65, 68, 89, 65, 77, 65, 65, 119, 65, 68, 73, 65, 77, 119, 65, 61, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 85, 103, 66, 80, 65, 68, 69, 65, 78, 103, 66, 67, 65, 70, 65, 65, 84, 119, 66, 84, 65, 68, 103, 65, 77, 81, 65, 119, 65, 68, 65, 65, 79, 81, 65, 122, 65, 68, 107, 65, 77, 119, 65, 119, 65, 68, 73, 65, 79, 65, 66, 83, 65, 69, 56, 65, 84, 103, 65, 119, 65, 68, 69, 65, 49, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 49, 50, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 50, 51, 78, 85, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 52, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 50, 53, 53, 48, 48, 48, 48, 52, 48, 52, 54, 54, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 53, 55, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 54, 56, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 49, 48, 48, 57, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 56, 65, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 57, 66, 48, 48, 48, 56, 52, 50, 48, 48, 67, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 49, 49, 68, 48, 48, 48, 48, 49, 54, 56, 55, 69, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 49, 54, 54, 70, 78, 85, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 71, 78, 85, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 82, 81, 66, 49, 65, 71, 99, 65, 90, 81, 66, 117, 65, 65, 61, 61, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 83, 81, 66, 117, 65, 71, 99, 65, 97, 81, 66, 117, 65, 71, 85, 65, 99, 103, 65, 61, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 53}
```

How can I translate this text into real data (English)

I know this might be a stupid question, but I don't even know where to start. Whatever I have tried from other stackoverflow question only returns the same string

```
DZ65Y6JmY0ykW0uuGGzWPVWQ==    000000000060000000000101102016120MQA5ADAAMQAyADIANgA0ADYAMAAwADIAMwA=                                                                                                                                        UgBPADEANgBCAFAATwBTADgAMQAwADAAOQAzADkAMwAwADIAOABSAE8ATgAwADEA1000000012000000023NU000000400000025500004046600000005700000006800000100900000008A00000009B00084200C00000011D00001687E00000166FNU000000GNU000000RQB1AGcAZQBuAA==                                                                                                        SQBuAGcAaQBuAGUAcgA=                                                                                                    5
```

If I try this:

```
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(text);
string decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```

I get:

```
The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.
```

Comment: First, these are clearly separate Base64 strings (`=` is a padding character at the end to ensure a correct length). Second, some of the strings have been cut off and can't be decoded due to invalid length. Whatever process is giving you these strings (OCR?) is flawed. Third, not all data in there is a plain string. The third one decodes to `RO16BPOS81009393028RON01` followed by binary data.

Comment: Yes, you are right. In order to read the bar-code I am using apps on my phone. Moreover, The form data contains IBAN so that is a valid IBAN, but I do not understand why would some of the strings be cut off